# if statements being skipped even when both expressions are true

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that populates a table with arrays. It has a doClick function so that when a user clicks on a cell it passes the row and column of the cell to the function. Example cell: onclick="doClick(0,1)"

```js
function doClick(row, col)
        {
            var top = row -1;
            var bottom = row +1;
            var left = col -1;
            var right = col +1;
            var swapped = false;
            
            if ((top != -1) && (cells[top][col].innerHTML = ""))
                {
                    cells[top][col].innerHTML = cells[row][col].innerHTML;
                    cells[row][col].innerHTML = "";
                    swapped = true;
                    
                }
            else if ((right != 4) && (cells[row][right].innerHTML = ""))
                {
                    cells[row][right].innerHTML = cells[row][col].innerHTML ;
                    cells[row][col].innerHTML = "";
                    swapped = true;
                }
            else if ((bottom != 4) && (cells[bottom][col].innerHTML = ""))
                {
                    cells[bottom][col].innerHTML = cells[row][col].innerHTML;
                    cells[row][col].innerHTML = "";
                    swapped = true;
                }
            else if ((left != -1) && (cells[row][left].inn  = ""))
                {  
                    cells[row][lef].innerHTML = cells[row][col].innerHTML;
                    cells[row][col].innerHTML = "";
                    swapped = true;
                }
            else
                {   
                    alert("Illegal Move.");
                }
```

. The problem is, even if both if expressions are true, the if statement is being skipped and it's falling through to the else statement. I've desk checked it and run it through the developer tools and checked values. A statement that was true on both expressions was skipped. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you console logged the condtion to make sure it 100% returns what you're expecting?

Comment: `cells[top][col].innerHTML = ""` that seems fishy - did you mean `==`?

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` and `===` for comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cells[row][right].innerHTML = ""`

is wrong.  You are missing the double (triple) `=`.

The correct way should be...

`cells[row][right].innerHTML === ""`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe there are a few typos or misconceptions in your code.

**A quick note about Conditions in an IF statement**
A statement like `(cells[top][col].innerHTML = "")` as a condition will always return true as this is setting `cells[top][col].innerHTML` as `""` or at least instantiating the variable. So, the proper condition to test absolutely true or false would be `(cells[top][col].innerHTML === "")`. However, you can get away with not even doing that and simply replace `(cells[top][col].innerHTML = "")` with `cells[top][col].innerHTML`. You may run into some other issues though is the variable is not instantiated already, either way. I would wrap the latter logic in an IF statement to check if `cells[top][col].innerHTML` is even instantiated.

To fix this, check out the following modifications I have made to your code.

```
function doClick(row, col)
{
    var top = row -1;
    var bottom = row +1;
    var left = col -1;
    var right = col +1;
    var swapped = false;

    if(typeof cells[top][col].innerHTML !== 'undefined' $$ cells[top][col].innerHTML !== null)
    {
        if ((top != -1) && cells[top][col].innerHTML !== '')
        {
            cells[top][col].innerHTML = cells[row][col].innerHTML;
            cells[row][col].innerHTML = "";
            swapped = true;
        }
        else if ((right != 4) && cells[row][right].innerHTML !== '')
        {
            cells[row][right].innerHTML = cells[row][col].innerHTML ;
            cells[row][col].innerHTML = "";
            swapped = true;
        }
        else if ((bottom != 4) && (cells[bottom][col].innerHTML))
        {
            cells[bottom][col].innerHTML = cells[row][col].innerHTML;
            cells[row][col].innerHTML = "";
            swapped = true;
        }
        else
        {   
            alert("Illegal Move.");
        }
    }
    else if (typeof cells[row][left].inn !== 'undefined' && (left != -1) && cells[row][left].inn !== '')
    {  
        cells[row][lef].innerHTML = cells[row][col].innerHTML;
        cells[row][col].innerHTML = "";
        swapped = true;
    }
    else
    {   
        alert("Illegal Move.");
    }
}
```

**An example working to demonstrate the above code**

```js
var testVar1 = '';
var testVar2 = 'Hello';
// var testVar3; <- Left this un-instantiated to test existance

// Testing if a var is empty but exists
if(typeof testVar1 !== 'undefined' && testVar1 !== null){
    if(testVar1 !== ''){
        alert('testVar1 has a value!');
    }{
        alert('testVar1 does not have a value!');
    }
}
// Testing if a var is empty but exists
if(typeof testVar2 !== 'undefined' && testVar2 !== null){
    if(testVar2 !== ''){
        if(testVar2 === 'Hello'){
            alert('testVar2 has a value! Value: ' + testVar2);
        }{
            alert('testVar2 has a value but it is not the one we expected.');
        }
    }{
        alert('testVar2 does not have a value!');
    }
}
// Test existance
if(typeof testVar3 !== 'undefined' && testVar3 !== null){
    alert('testVar3 exists!');
}else{
    alert('testVar3 does not exist!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: Most certainly! I did just update it to be a little more accurate.

Comment: Actually, attribution statements always return the value that is being set, in this case, an empty string. Plot twist: empty string is a falsy value which means it is considered to be false by logic checks in javascript. Other falsy values in javascript are the number 0 (zero), null, undefined, NaN and, of course, false.

Comment: The assignment operator was the problem. Thank you so much. It's fresh eyes that does the trick. I stared at that code for hours and never saw that.

Comment: @PedroLima , Correct. However, to provide a working example that solved the direct question i simply tested for undefined. However, to provide an accurate demonstration, I have updated the snippet above. P.S. Checking for `null` covers 0 and NaN as well. Depending on the JS engine, it will also check for `undefined`.

Comment: @Mishelbi Excellent! Im glad it helped. If this answer helped please mark it as the answer to your question. Thank you!